# Normal families $\mathscr{F}\subset \mathscr{H}(D)$

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I have to decide if the following families are normal.

1) $\mathscr{F}=\{f\in \mathscr{H}(D): f(0)=0\ \& \ |f'(z)|(1-|z|^2)\leq1,\ \forall z\in D\}$

2) $\mathscr{F}=\{f\in \mathscr{H}(D): f(0)=0\ \& \ |f''(z)|(1-|z|^2)\leq1,\ \forall z\in D\}$

I want to use the Montel's theorem, so I have to see if the families are uniformly bounded, but I don't know how to use the conditions on the derivatives. Hints?

Comment: For 1, $f_n'$ is normal so has convergent subsequence, and $f_n(0)=0$ ensures the subsequence of $f_n$ converges too; for 2 we only get $f_n"$ normal so the $z$ term is not controllable, and for example $nz$ satisfies the condition but it is not normal

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand 2), but for 1) I don't know where are we using the condition $|f'(z)|(1-|z|^2)\leq 1$

Comment: @Conrad Can you explain whey $(f_n')$ is  normal in 1)?

Comment: Condition implies $|f'|$ uniformly bounded by $\frac{1}{1-r^2}$, when $|z| \le r < 1$ and all compacts of the open disc are inside one of those closed discs of slightly lower radius